# my app currently doesn't start from the main page and instead goes straight to the AR camera

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia, uiapplicationdelegate

I just built an AR app using unity and vuforia. the app runs perfectly in android, however when i run it for iOS, the app doesn't go to the main page and instead jumps straight into the AR Camera even when i navigate in the app to go back to the main page from the AR camera, the AR Camera automatically comes on..

everything was alright before Xcode 9, and after the update this main thread checker thing has been giving me quite a lot of headache.. i couldn't find any solution except for **DispatchQueue.main.async {** but i don't know where to put this at.. please help~ this is getting frustrating.. :(

```
inline UnityAppController*  GetAppController()
{
    return (UnityAppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

in Xcode, the purple warning shows **-[UIApplication delegate] must be used from main thread only**

Answer (score 0):

```
// NSOperationQueue
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Your code for getting the Application Delegate: GetAppController()
}];

// GCD
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Your code for getting the Application Delegate: GetAppController()
});
```

You are calling the C++ method, so probably use the second one would be better. BTW don't forget add this to your header(or .m) file `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`